# How to convert true-type font to open-type?

Tags: html, fonts, font-face, font-size, truetype

I have been using `Calibri` font in my web pages for too long using `@font-face` but the thing is including such big font file reduces web page loading speed drastically! But I have seen that a font in `ttf` format is more bigger than the one in `opt` or `open-type` format (Am I right or not?). That's why I want a font converter. Can anyone provide me a one or can give me a link to get it. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having wonderful success using [Google's Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)  They don't give you a a million options font-wise, but they're loaded off of Google's screaming fast CDN which undoubtedly will deliver them much faster than 99% of the hosting solution us mere mortals have access to.  Since they are served from the edge off a different host than the rest of your content, the load advantage should be quite impressive.

As easy as it is to find a font, copy, and paste, I've had little reason to fight with anything else.